# MDB tries to find Destination property in JNDI instead of looking for the queue with that actual name when Java app and IBM MQ are run with Docker

Tags: java, docker, jboss, ibm-mq

I have

1. a Docker image providing a IBM MQ queue with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ibmcom/mq

ENV LICENSE=accept
ENV MQ_QMGR_NAME=QMGR

COPY config.mqsc /etc/mqm/
COPY setup.sh /etc/mqm/
USER root
RUN chmod +x /etc/mqm/setup.sh

EXPOSE 1414 9443

CMD ["/etc/mqm/setup.sh"]
```

with config.mqsc just defining my queue `DEFINE QLOCAL('MY.TEST.QUEUE') REPLACE`
and setup.sh being

```
#!/bin/bash

# Apply configuration
runmqsc < /etc/mqm/config.mqsc

# Start MQ server
QMGR_NAME=$MQ_QMGR_NAME
strmqm $QMGR_NAME
```

2. a Java EE application that has a MessageDriven Bean connected to that queue. The Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:latest

ENV WILDFLY_CONFIG=standalone-full.xml
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone-full.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
WORKDIR /app

COPY /target/my-app.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

I configured my MDBs like that:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "My.Test.Queue")
})
```

I started both Docker containers on the same network:

```
docker network create testnetwork
docker run --network=testnetwork -d -p 8080:8080 --name app-test-container app-test
docker run --network=testnetwork -d -p 1414:1414 -p 9443:9443 --name queue-test-container queue-test
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
AMQ153005: Unable to retrieve "MY.TEST.QUEUE" from JNDI. 
Creating a new "javax.jms.Queue" named "jms.queue.MY.TEST.QUEUE" to be used by the MDB.
```

So for some reason, the MDB seems to try looking for a JNDI resource instead of the queue of the actual provided name. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false")`.